# \ref{lst:...} does not reference correctly to \label{lst:...} in subsection

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, listings, labels

I'm writing a document in which I have some figures, tables and source code (lstlistings), all with numbered captions e.g. Figure 3.2.1 Caption

All are working properly except in subsections the a `\label{lst:code}` that shows in the document as Code 3.2.1, where 3 corresponds to the chapter, 2 to the section and 1 to a continuous number of listings within the section, the corresponding `\ref{lst:code}` would Show as 3.2.2 where the second 2 corresponds to the subsection instead.

All other references work normally. Even if I set the numbering to subsection (with 4 numbers instead 3) the number of the reference (lstlisting) stays with 3 numbers.

Can I somehow manitulate how \ref{} is set for the lstlistings?

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}
\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}
\lstset{
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\subsection{Program.cs}
\subsection{Program.cs}

Code \ref{lst:code}

\lstset{caption=Code}\label{lst:code}
\begin{lstlisting}
static void Main() {
Application.Run(new Form());
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This Returns:

- Chapter 4
- 4.3 Section
- 4.3.2 Subsection
- 4.3.1 the number of the Codecaption
- 4.3.2 the number of the Reference but this should be 4.3.1

Comment: You are doing something wrong but as you are not showing what you are doing it is difficult to say what exactly. Make a complete example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: presumably you have `\label` in the wrong place (eg before the `\caption`) but as you have shown no example that can only be a guess.

Comment: I won't debug your large code on overleaf.

Comment: this question is archived forever but your link is not stable even if people agree to follow it. Please make a small example and add it to the question.

Comment: Added some sample code

Comment: I tried to guess how to make your fragment into a document but get `! Package chngcntr Error: lstlisting is not a counter.` please make it an example that shows the problem.

Comment: This the whole document after I removed everything that is not necessary for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
\lstset{caption=Code}\label{lst:code}
```

you need to supply the `\label` using the `label` key-value:

```
\lstset{caption=Code,label=lst:code}
```

See the top of p 18 in the current [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).

[image]